# Pass hash in URL with jquery and make mysql query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, getjson

Okay, so I have this situation.
I have a table called skills, with a simple schema

```
id|name

It has records like

1|Cashier
2|Software Developer
3|C#
4|C# 3.0
5|C# Programming
```

So, on front-end I have a textbox with drop-down that makes ajax call and fills the drop-down with results of ajax call as you type, like

```
    $.getJSON(that.path + "?q=" + encodeURIComponent(keyword) , function(result){
        if (result.length == 0) {
```

to get matching results.

I get proper results if I am searching for words like 'Software' and 'Cashier'.
But problem is when I search for any skills with '#' symbol in it.

`that.path` leads to a php function

```
public function findSkills() {
    print_r($_GET['q']);
```

If I want to search for all skills with '#' in it, my URL for ajax call becomes something like

```
http://somedomain.xyz/skills/findSkills?q=%23
```

Then when I print $_GET['q'], i get nothing printed.
How can I overcome this issue?

Expected SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM skills  WHERE (`name` LIKE '%#%') ORDER BY `id` ASC  LIMIT 10
```

**I have read that any portion in URL after hash(including hash) is not sent to server.** If this is the case, is there any other way to implement this which will allow me to make SQL query to fetch records with '#'?

Any help will be surely appreciated. Please let me know if I am missing on any other data/more code if required. I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: This should be possible with `$_POST` instead of `$_GET` I think.

Comment: Or you could in javascript check if `#` is being tried to send and change it to a custom value and check on the server if the custom value is set.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works fine with the following test snippet:

```
if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
  echo json_encode($_GET['q']);
  exit;
}
?>
<form>
  <input name="q" id="q">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script>
$('button').click(function() {
  $.getJSON(
    'test.php?q=' + encodeURIComponent(q.value),
    function(result) {
      $('body').append($('<p>' + result + '</p>'));
    }
  );
  return false;
});
</script>
```

It worth mention that looking at the HTTP request (with some tool such as Firebug) and entering e.g. `C#` it reports:

> GET /test/stackOverflow/test.php?**q=C%23** HTTP/1.1

while using `'test.php?q=' + q.value` instead of `'test.php?q=' + encodeURIComponent(q.value)` it reports:

> GET /test/stackOverflow/test.php?**q=C** HTTP/1.1

In other words, while it's true that "any portion in URL after hash (including hash) is not sent to server", this rule is perfectly bypassed when using `encodeURIComponent()`.

So it confirms that, if you write it like you showed it *should* work.
Your current issue is likely a simple other error somewhere.